# How to auto-expand the Exception details in Visual Studio's Exception Assistant dialog box

Tags: visual-studio, exception, visual-studio-2015

I realize this is a trivial question (I'm always trying to reduce mouse clicks in my work!), but it annoys me that the VS Exception Assistant dialog box (the one that appears when you click "View Detail..." on an unhandled Exception) opens UN-expanded. You have to manually aim and click on the tiny little expand button in order to view the InnerException or other metadata. It makes no sense, really. Does anyone know of a way to circumvent the default behavior and force the table to expand automatically when the view is opened?
[image]

Comment: You will have to expand it till you get the inner exception null. Unless that first default expansion will not be useful.

Comment: VS2015 is where this dialog really started to suffer, it was replaced in VS2017.  You can still get the "good" version with Tools > Options > Debugging > General, tick the "Use Managed Compatibility Mode".  Few reasons to reset it again, it also avoids a boatload of debugger bugs, unless you really need return value debugging or E+C in x64 mode.

Comment: @HansPassant - the setting of that textbox doesn't seem to have any effect on the layout of the "View Detail" screen for me (in VS2015). I guess I'll just have to wait until I can upgrade to 17.